# how to identify an object with the same name with name property

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to find out an object with same name with different value? Here i am interested to identify based on the name only. Do we have index like property provided in QTP. In QTP, if two buttons with same can be distinguished by index, first button with index 0 and second button with 1.

Is there way to do the same in WebDriver?

I want to identify object with name meaning "By.name". How can i do that?

Thanks,
Uday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options to achieve it (examples in `java`):

- using `findElements` and get the appropriate element from the list of resulting web elements:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.name("test"));
  WebElement element = elements.get(0);
  ```
- use `xpath` based approach (indexing starts from 1 here):

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@name="test"][1]'));
  ```

Comment: Sry, somehow findElements didn't came to my thought. Yes using findElements we can get it worked.

Comment: @Uday thanks, glad it worked, is there anything I can add to the answer?

Comment: Thanks alecxe, the moment i got this question, i started thinking keeping QTP in mind. So missed this basic thought. Anyways you kept me in right track.

Comment: @Uday okay, then consider "closing" the topic by accepting the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery style syntax in your search..

For example in Chrome tools `$('css selector')[0]` will get you the first occurrence of some element.

Selenium comes with a JavaScript driver so you could instantiate that and use that against your site to leverage jQuery.